# How does Emacs select which minor modes to list in the mode line?

Tags: emacs, elisp, modeline

I plan to customize mode line in Emacs in near future, and i don't understand the algorithm behind listing minor modes in the mode line.

In section «1.3 The Mode Line» of Emacs manual it says: *«MINOR is a list of some of the enabled "minor modes"»*

While in section «23.2 Minor Modes» it says: *«Most buffer-local minor modes say in the mode line when they are enabled»*

However i have ErgoEmacs minor mode listed, which is global. Can somebody explain the mechanism behind this and preferably point at various elisp sources responsible for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is specified for each individual mode, by the mode's own definition.

If you read on to section 23.3.3 - Defining Minor Modes:

> The string LIGHTER says what to display in the mode line when the mode is enabled; if it is `nil', the mode is not displayed in the mode line.

See:

<kbd>M-:</kbd> `(info "(elisp) Defining Minor Modes")` <kbd>RET</kbd>

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `define-minor-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>

See also http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DelightedModes which facilitates easy customisation of the mode line display for both major and minor modes.

Answer (score 7):

You can change what is displayed for a specific minor mode by doing something like the following

```
(setcar (cdr (assq 'yas/minor-mode minor-mode-alist)) " ¥")
```

which will display "  ¥" for [yasnippet mode](https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet).  I do this a lot, especially for modes that I often use since it shortens my mode-line considerably.

Comment: Gives me an error: Wrong type argument